A quotient space which is not Hausdorff
I have been working on Problem 3-17 in Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds. Here is Problem 3-17
This problem shows that the conclusion of Proposition 3.57 need not be true if the quotient map is not assumed to be open. Let $X$ be the following subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
\begin{equation*}
  X = \left(\left]0, 1\right[ \times \left]0, 1\right[\right) \cup \{(0, 0)\} \cup \{(1, 0)\}.
\end{equation*}
For any $\varepsilon \in \left]0, 1\right[$, let $C_{\varepsilon}$ and $D_{\varepsilon}$ be the sets
\begin{align*}
        C_{\varepsilon} & = \{(0, 0)\} \cup \left(\left]0, \frac{1}{2}\right[\times \left]0, \varepsilon\right[\right), \\
        D_{\varepsilon} & = \{(1, 0)\} \cup \left(\left]\frac{1}{2}, 1\right[\times \left]0, \varepsilon\right[\right).
\end{align*}
Define a basis $\mathscr{B}$ for a topology on $X$ consisting of all open rectangles of the form $\left]{a_{1}, b_{1}}\right[ \times \left]{a_{2}, b_{2}}\right[$ with $0\leq a_{1} < b_{1}\leq 1$ and $0\leq a_{2} < b_{2} \leq 1$, together with all subsets of the form $C_{\varepsilon}$ or $D_{\varepsilon}$.
(a) Show that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis for a topology on $X$.
(b) Show that this topology is Hausdorff.
(c) Show that the subset $A = \{(0, 0)\} \cup \left( \left]0, \frac{1}{2}\right] \times \left]{0,1}\right[ \right)$ is closed in $X$.
(d) Let $\sim$ be the relation on $X$ generated by $a \sim a'$ for all $a, a'\in A$. Show that $\sim$ is closed in $X\times X$.
(e) Show that the quotient space $X/A$ obtained by collapsing $A$ to a point is not Hausdorff.

I have managed to prove every part but (e). Here is how I have been thinking about it so far:
To show that $X/A$ is not Hausdorff, I will find two distinct points in $X/A$ which are not separated by disjoint neighborhoods. If I choose two different points from the complement of $A$ (which are inequivalent) then their equivalence classes are separated by disjoint neighborhoods. So instead, I have to pick a point of $A$ and a point of $X\smallsetminus A$ and then show that disjoint neighborhoods cannot separate their equivalence classes. However, I am so convinced that the quotient space is instead Hausdorff, and couldn't show otherwise.
Could you give me some hints for part (e)?

You should use $(a,b)$, $(a,b]$ and $[a,b)$ instead of $]a,b[$, $]a,b]$ and $[a,b[$ respectively.

I chose to use square brackets instead of parentheses for the closed and half-open intervals because the statement contains a lot of parentheses with different meanings already: open intervals, order pairs, and indications of the order of operators.

@AnotherUser: there is nothing wrong with using $]a, b[$ for $(a, b)$ etc. It's not my preference, but it's very common in the literature.

Your arguments could be streamlined but you are right that the points $q((0,0))$ and $q((1,0))$ do not have disjoint neighbourhoods. Parts a,b,c of the problem should be easy for you.

@DuongNgo If you believe you got an answer then you should post that as an answer instead of writing that inside of your question.

@SoumikMukherjee I was reluctant when I got an answer. Thank you for encouraging me to post my answer.

@Jochen Thank you for your comment. Turns out, there was redundancy in the proof that I added to the question.

Here is my proof for part (e)
Let $q: X \to X/A$ be the quotient map that induces the quotient topology.
We will show that two points (equivalence classes) $q((0, 0))$ and $q((1, 0))$ cannot be separated by disjoint neighborhoods.
Any neighborhood $U$ of $q((1, 0))$ must contain a set $D_{\varepsilon_{0}}$ for some $\varepsilon_{0} \in \left]0, 1\right[$.
Let $V$ be a neighborhood of $q((0, 0))$ in $X/A$ then the preimage $q^{-1}(V)$ is a neighborhood containing $A$, since $q^{-1}((0, 0)) = A$. For every $\delta \in \left]0, 1\right[$, $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \delta\right) \in A \subseteq q^{-1}(V)$, so $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \delta\right)$ has a neighborhood $N_{\delta}$ contained in $q^{-1}(V)$.
According to part (b), the basis for the topology on $X$ consists of open rectangles (whose vertices are within $\left]0,1\right[\times\left]0,1\right[$) and sets of type $C_{\varepsilon}, D_{\varepsilon}$. Because (for every $\delta \in \left]0,1\right[$) the point $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \delta\right)$ doesn't lie in any set of type $C_{\varepsilon}$ or $D_{\varepsilon}$, there is an open rectangle $R_{\delta}$ such that $\left(\frac{1}{2}, \delta\right) \in R_{\delta} \subseteq N_{\delta} \subseteq q^{-1}(V)$. Consider a $\delta \in \left]0, 1\right[$ such that $\delta < \varepsilon_{0}$, then we have an open rectangle $R_{\delta}$ containing points with $x$-ordinate greater than $\frac{1}{2}$ and $y$-ordinate less than $\varepsilon_{0}$ - such points lie in $D_{\varepsilon_{0}}$. This implies that $V$ is not disjoint from $D_{\varepsilon_{0}}$, hence $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint.
Hence any neighborhoods of $q((0, 0))$ and $q((1, 0))$ are not disjoint. Thus $X/A$ is not Hausdorff.
